# i experienced a "code=UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION"-error while learning how to code

Tags: solidity, hardhat, testnets, error, test

```
Error: cannot override "wertgesendet" (operation="overrides", overrides=["wertgesendet"], code=UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION, version=contracts/5.5.0)
```

guys i am receiving this error message while learning how to code with vsc.
i am testing with hardhat, chai

i hope i can give you everything what you need to help me :)
my code looks like this:

```
const { getNamedAccounts, ethers, network } = require("hardhat")
const { assert, expect } = require("chai")
const { developmentChains } = require("../../helper-hardhat-config")

developmentChains.includes(network.name)
    ? describe.skip
    : describe("FundMe", async function() {
          let deployer
          let fundme
          const wertgesendet = ethers.utils.parseEther("1")

          beforeEach(async function() {
              deployer = (await getNamedAccounts()).deployer
              fundme = await ethers.getContract("BitteSpenden", deployer)
          })
          it("erlaubt leute zu spenden und abzuheben", async function() {
              await fundme.spenden({ wertgesendet })
              await fundme.abzuheben()
              const endBalance = await fundme.provider.getBalance(
                  fundme.address
              )
              assert.equal(endBalance.toString(), "0")
          })
      })
```

this is my config:

```
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle")
require("hardhat-gas-reporter")
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan")
require("dotenv").config()
require("solidity-coverage")
require("hardhat-deploy")
// You need to export an object to set up your config
// Go to https://hardhat.org/config/ to learn more
/**
 * @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig
 */

//CONFIG IST DER EINGANGSPUNKT FÜR DAS PROGRAMM::: BEDEUTET DASS ES ALS ERSTES ANGESCHAUT WIRD WENN COMPILED/DEPLOYED

const COINMARKETCAP_API_KEY = process.env.COINMARKETCAP_API_KEY || ""
const GOERLI_RPC_URL =
    process.env.GOERLI_RPC_URL ||
    "https://eth-mainnet.alchemyapi.io/v2/your-api-key"
const PRIVATE_KEY =
    process.env.PRIVATE_KEY ||
    "0x11ee3108a03081fe260ecdc106554d09d9d1209bcafd46942b10e02943effc4a"
const ETHERSCAN_API_KEY = process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY || ""

module.exports = {
    defaultNetwork: "hardhat",
    networks: {
        hardhat: {
            chainId: 31337
            // gasPrice: 130000000000,
        },
        goerli: {
            url: GOERLI_RPC_URL,
            accounts: [PRIVATE_KEY],
            chainId: 5,
            blockConfirmations: 6
        }
    },
    solidity: {
        compilers: [
            {
                version: "0.8.7"
            },
            {
                version: "0.6.6"
            }
        ]
    },
    etherscan: {
        apiKey: ETHERSCAN_API_KEY
        // customChains: [], // uncomment this line if you are getting a TypeError: customChains is not iterable
    },
    gasReporter: {
        enabled: true,
        currency: "USD",
        outputFile: "gas-report.txt",
        noColors: true
        // coinmarketcap: COINMARKETCAP_API_KEY,
    },
    namedAccounts: {
        deployer: {
            default: 0, // here this will by default take the first account as deployer
            1: 0 // similarly on mainnet it will take the first account as deployer. Note though that depending on how hardhat network are configured, the account 0 on one network can be different than on another
        }
    },
    mocha: {
        timeout: 500000
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the error lies in the way of calling this method:

```
  await fundme.spenden({ wertgesendet })
```

Without knowing the config of your contract , the `{}` are understood as the overrides like `gasLimit` `value`,...etc.

Can you please share your `spendme`contract code?

Hope it helps!

Comment: first of all thanks for your answer.
the code where i declared the function is this one:
`function spenden() public payable {
         require (msg.value.Umwandlungsrate(s_priceFeed) >= minimumUSD,"nicht genug gespendet");  
        s_Spender.push(msg.sender);
        s_AddresseZuGespendeterMenge[msg.sender] += msg.value;  
    }`

im german just explaining quick what i mean with these words:
spenden = fundMe
Umwandundlungsrate = conversionRate for Eth/Usd
s_AddresseZuGespeicherterMenge = AddressToAmountFunded (THIS IS A MAPPING)
s_Spender= s_Funders( THIS IS AN ADDRESS ARRAY)

Comment: Hey, Ich spreche deutch!. You should call the function like this:
 `await fundme.spenden({ value:wertgesendet })`

Comment: danke dir vielmals donoso ich habe vergessen value hinzuzufügen und das programm hat versucht den wert von wertgesendet zu überschreiben. jetzt funktioniert es.
danke dir :)